# Using XML for storing complex form structures?

Tags: xml, zend-framework

I'm currently working with Zend Framework for the first-time, i've been contemplating how to produce complex form structures without a load of bulky of HTML.

My question is whether it would be a good idea to store the form schema in an XML file, then use a Model in Zend to parse it & pass to a viewer that could load form as HTML i.e. using form helper/ placeholders?

Let me know if this makes sense! & if there is a simpler/ better option!

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `Zend_Form`. 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html

You can generate Zend_Form instances from XML files, ini files, or arrays which would be essentially what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that generating form as XML is huge overkill unless you need to have them generated based on user's data. For form used for adding a new Article to DB is XML/INI/etc just pure overkill. You can very well use class that extends Zend_Form. Only reason to use XML is when user is generating those forms. **It will be very slow!**

Comment: It won't be slow if it's not parsed too often, i.e. cached inappropriately.